# NSTableCellView shows nothing if it's a group cell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm trying to make a simple view-based `NSTableView` with groups and regular cells. Every cell is drawn correct and shows everything I need unless I add this method to my `NSTableViewDelegate/DataSource`:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, isGroupRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    return (tableContent[row] as NSDictionary)["group"] != nil
}
```

It works just fine, but cells that become group cells show nothing. I've tried it on different cell types, but still nothing, just a semi-transparent gray background. Even if I add something like

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSColor(calibratedRed: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 1).setFill()
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
}
```

to my group cell class I'll get only a semi-transparent gray background.

Comment: Can you show NSTableViewDelegate's viewForTableColumn?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you make the same mistake as I did today.

When using `func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, isGroupRow row: Int) -> Bool`, the `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` no longer provides `tableColumn` for grouped rows, which means `tableColumn` is nil. So if you implementation relies on `tableColumn.identifier`, it is unreliable.

You should change your implementation to relying on `row` with grouped rows.